# why are key value pairs being added twice to state?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following function:

```
handleAddItem(s) {

  var key = Object.keys(s)[0];
  var value = s[key];

  var allItems = {...this.state.items};      

      allItems[key] = allItems[key];
      allItems[key].push({name: value});


  var ourItems = {};
      ourItems = allItems[key];
      ourItems.push({name:  value });        


  this.setState({items: allItems});

}
```

I realize that ourItems isn't really suppose to be doing anything but why when those three lines are added are the key value pairs being added twice to state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only primitives in JavaScript are passed by value. Everything else is passed by reference. 
By setting `ourItems = allItems[key]` you make the `ourItems` variable point to the `allItems[key]` array. It does not copy the array. Because of that you actually push the object twice into the same array.

Comment: can you set state this way?